# Linux group user permissions

Tags: java, tomcat

1. I have a group of users, I want them to be able to start & kill each others process in Centos 7. I used visudo to add this line, in which tomcat is the group name:
   %tomcat localhost=(%tomcat) NOPASSWD:/bin/kill
   but after reboot it is not working.
2. if user A started tomcat, log files were created under user A. If tomcat was stopped, then user B can not start tomcat as user B has no permissions to log files created by A. A & B are in the same group & the group have full permissions to log directory. How to let B be able to start tomcat?

Can anyone help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to set the tomcat group as default group owner for your log directory. Here is a description how to do it: https://superuser.com/questions/437781/how-do-i-set-default-group-ownership-for-files-in-a-directory

Comment: @BalázsNemes Thanks it worked for question 2. Any idea about question 1?

Comment: As I understand the simplest form of a sudo rule is like this: `%tomcat ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/kill` So may be you can start with this and then experiment with tweaking.